# Haskell: `reverse` or right `cons`, which is more efficient

Tags: list, haskell

Since I learned Haskell some time ago, I keep seeing people `reverse` lists, just to the reverse them back a moment later. The following function for splitting a string with a delimiter is an example:

```
splitOn ::Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOn sep str = s_word str []
   where s_word []     w = [reverse w]
         s_word (c:cs) w = if (c == sep) then reverse w : s_word cs []
                           else s_word cs (c:w)
```

I think the reason is the "lack" of a right/reverse cons operator like:

```
rcons xs x = xs ++ [x]
```

Of course, `rcons` is by far less efficient than the `cons` operator (`:`).

But the above code seems to introduce its own inefficiency by using `reverse`. I was wondering whether it is more efficient or less efficient than the following variant:

```
splitOn' ::Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOn' sep str = s_word str []
   where s_word []     w = [w]
         s_word (c:cs) w = if (c == sep) then w : s_word cs []
                           else s_word cs (rcons w c)
```

Both functions seem to achieve the same thing. I think the second version seems more intuitive (though maybe less clever). Are there any pitfalls using `rcons` like this? (infinite list, laziness etc.)

Thanks.

P.S. output:

```
*Main> splitOn' ',' "a,b,"
["a","b",""]
```

Comment: If I was stuck with a problem that I thought really needed efficient consing on both ends, I would use [Data.Sequence from the containers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html)

Comment: Note also that you can write `splitOn` efficiently with no reversing *or* `rcons`ing. Consider using `break (== x)`.

Comment: It stands to hope that the internal implementation of `reverse` is a bit more sane than the naive Haskell implementation. It *can* be a constant time implementation. But then again, I don't know any implementation-specifics of, say, ghc.

Comment: @bitmask, the built-in Haskell lists are genuine singly-linked lists in all traditional implementations (including GHC). Basically, that's because anything fancier would *slow down* at least some code that uses them appropriately. If you need something fancier, you can get it from one package or another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If "double reverse" is used to just add a single element, `rcons` is likely to be more efficient because it will only traverse the input list once whereas each `reverse` will do so once making two traversals in total.

However in the `splitOn'` example you give, `reverse` is only being used once per output word, as the value is being accumulated in reversed form to begin with. More importantly, `(:)` will be used several times before `reverse` is called.

In your alternative with `rcons`, there would be a linear traversal of the list for each new element, whereas with `reverse` there will only be a single linear traversal once the result is ready.

Comment: Note that an alternative is to use DList (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist), which is more efficient than a right-cons and often more efficient than reversing a list.